# plt.yticks dont show all of y ticks label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want the y-axis to display the y-ticks label from 0 to 40, and the step is 2.

But when I use `plt.yticks(np.arange(0,40,step=2))`, the plot is inexplicable . It doesnt show all the tick labels, and the range is uncorrect!

How to solve this problem.

**abstract code**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = ['15.0','14.0','13.0','12.0']
x = ['1','2','3','4']

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,40,step=2))
plt.show()
```

**the output doesnt show all the tick label**

[image: dont show all the tick label]

*When I use `set_yticklabels` to add all the tick labels*
**The output doesnt show the actual value**

**code**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = ['15.0','14.0','13.0','12.0']
x = ['1','2','3','4']

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,40,step=2))
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(np.arange(0,40,step=2))
plt.show()
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to invert your y-axis with `plt.gca().invert_yaxis()`?

Comment: Nope. I want to show all the ticks label on y-axis.

Comment: The `invert_yaxis()` would keep your labels but make them go from 40 to zero decreasing upwards which may not be what you want. Otherwise can you try and use some random data to provide an example? I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: OK, I will abstract my code

Comment: i don't think you want strings for `x` and `y`.. When you convert them before plotting, `plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 40, step=2))` should behave as expected.

Comment: Thanks! It works！I nerver thought  about it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your data consists of strings. Accordingly, the axis labels are more like categories than anything else, because `matplotlib` does not compare strings by their values *if they were converted to integers*. Consider the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = ['1', '2', '3', '50']
x = ['1', '2', '3', '-200']

plt.plot(x,y)
```

That produces the following plot:

[image]

If you modify your data types, you will not face this problem.

That said, instead of setting your tick ranges manually, you may want to consider using the tick locators in `matplotlib.ticker`. An example:

```
x = [1, 3, 8, 20]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(3.5))
```

[image]